# iOS VoiceOver does not read whether a UITableview cell is enabled or not

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, accessibility, voiceover

I have a UITableview cell with some accessibility for the texts within the cell. The only problem it does not tell if a cell is enabled or not . The voice over reads the texts but does not tell if the cell is enabled or not . Any help with that .

Answer (score 0):

The way I've it is by handling myself the state. Depends on the state, it is the text you assign to the `accessibilityLabel`

```swift
let model = dataSource.cell(at: indexPath)

if model.isEnabled {
   cell.accessibilityLabel = "my text to be read by voice over"
} else {
   cell.accessibilityLabel = "Not enabled"
}
```